# Solutions of differential equations on closed intervals

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm wondering about solutions of differential equations on closed intervals. For some context, this is something that seems to show up in problems with a boundary condition. Consider some differential equation
\begin{equation*}
y' = f(x,y)
\end{equation*}

While on open intervals it's quite clear how to define a solution of this equation, I'm not sure what a sensible way to define solutions on closed intervals would be.

**(1)** The simplest approach would be to consider $y$ to be a solution on $[a,b]$, if it's a solution on $(a-\delta, b+\delta)$ for some $\delta > 0$.

**(2)** Here's the alternative, less restrictive approach - we say $y$ is a solution of the differential equation above on $[a,b]$, if it is true that
\begin{equation*}
y'(t) = f(x,y(t)) \qquad \forall t \in (a,b)
\end{equation*}
and also
\begin{align*}
y_{+}'(a) &= f(a,y(a))\\
y_{-}'(b) &= f(b,y(b))
\end{align*}

How do these approaches compare, and are there any pathological issues that might occur if we use the **2** rather than **1**?

As an example, if $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$, can any solution of type **2** be extended to a solution of type **1** ?

Comment: As far as I understand, you could define: $T(\varphi)(x) = y_0 + \int^{x}_{a}f(t,\varphi(t))\ dt$, and the question could be reduced to asking for solutions of $T(\varphi) = \varphi$. If $\varphi$ satisfies the differential equation on the open interval $(a,b)$ with being continuous in $[a,b]$, then it also satisfies the above equation.

Comment: Probably some restrictions are required on $\varphi'$ needing to be bounded and integrable on $(a,b)$ but other than that the value of the derivative at the end point doesn't matter for this kind of extended solution